# Dynamic Body Class for Active menu styling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m1ov5o7q/1/) menu in my web page. So I include this to index.php

But everytime I click a menu and load a new page, active menu style (.active class) is gone and it turns to its initial style. So users can't figure out which page they are visiting right then.

I wonder if I can figure this out with body classes? For example, can I say "if body class is this than make that menu class active" So I could change active menu style and understand which page I am visiting.

I have 3 menu and each menu has at least 5 submenu.

```html
  <?php 
 $pages = array('pageA','pageB','pageC');

  if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
   
   if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
      $page = $_GET['page']; 
     $id = $_GET['id']; }
   else {
    header("Location:error.php"); 
    } }
  else { $page='empty';}  
  ?>
 
 <body class = "<?php echo $page $id?>">
```

This is my menu structure:

```html
<ul>
 <li class="active">
   <h3>pageA</h3>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php?pageA&id=1">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageA&id=2">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageA&id=3">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageA&id=4">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageA&id=5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
     </li>
 <li>
   <h3>pageB</h3>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php?pageB&id=1">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageB&id=2">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageB&id=3">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageB&id=4">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php?pageB&id=5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
     </li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: `<body class="<?php echo $page . "_" . $id; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with jQuery.

on `$(document).ready`you can:

```
var currentPage = window.location.href;
alert(currentPage);// just a test

if(currentPage == "www.stackoverflow.com/rocks"){
    // style the body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PHP, but you should do something like this:

Set a global PHP variable that sets which page you are on.

Something like $Global_Page = "Home";

Give each list item a unique id to match the page name.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="Home">
      <h3>pageA</h3>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Then use JS to apply the active class to the correct tab, by passing it the PHP var. You should include this little script in the nav include file.

```
<script>
$(function(){
var x= //However you render you php var. $Global_Page
$("ul$nav li#"+x).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```